# Devising equation using exponential

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponential-function, exponential-distribution

So, this is a bit hard to explain. I want to devise an equation that turns the numbers on the left into the numbers on the right.

8 = 20

20 = 40

32 = 80

44 = 160

56 = 320

As well as all the other values in between 8-56. As in, the numbers between 8-20 have a proportional value between 20-40. Numbers between 32-44 have a proportional value between 80-160 ect.

The values on the left go up linearly and the values on the right go up exponentially.

I hope this makes sense. It's quite hard to explain. But would appreciate any help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Increasing by 12 doubles the result so
something like
$20*2^{(x-8)/12}$.

Comment: +1 : nice catch.  I was fumbling with my calculator looking at the change in proportions $[8 : 20] \cdots [56:320].$

Comment: great. Thanks a lot